# Array multiply pairs

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I must create code in C# to:

- Ask the user to enter an arbitrary set of numbers into an array and display all the entered numbers.
  I done this part and the code is working properly
- Then multiply pairs of numbers together and display the result. If you have an odd number of numbers then just display the last number.

  E.G.
  2 3 8 4 become 6 32 
  2 3 8 4 7 become 6 32 7

My problem is with the odd arrays. if the arrays has even number of element it's no problem, but if the arrays has odd number of elements there are errors, never print the last element.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArrayDisplay
{
    class Array
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[9];
            int userInput = -1;
            int itt = 0;
            int count = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a integer number or -1 to exit:");
            userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            count++;
            while (userInput != -1 && itt<array.Length)
            {

                array[itt] = userInput;
                itt++;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter a integer number or -1 to exit:");
                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                count++;
            }
              Console.WriteLine("The array contains: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                Console.Write(" {0} , "  ,array[i]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("count {0}",count-1);

            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i] * array[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i] * array[i + 1])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 7*0=0, try below:

```
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} , ", i == count - 2 ? array[i] : array[i] * array[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i += 2)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i] * array[i + 1]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I spent 3 hours trying to find the error.

Comment: You should learn to mark a breakpoint to debug your program, and you may see the value of your variable clearly in the debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] array = new int[9];
            int userInput = -1;
            int itt = 0;
            int count = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a integer number or -1 to exit:");
            userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            count++;
            while (userInput != -1 && itt < array.Length)
            {

                array[itt] = userInput;
                itt++;
                if (count == 9) break;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a integer number or -1 to exit:");
                userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The array contains: ");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("count {0}", count);

            if (count % 2 == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i] * array[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (



                    int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 1)
                {
                    if (i == 7)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i] * array[i + 1]);
                        break;
                    }

                    Console.Write(" {0} , ", array[i] * array[i + 1]);


                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine()
```

;